# Session variable error is not working. Https

Tags: php, session, variables, https

After 3 days of fighting I am done. I made php code for activate account on my website (email reflink). Actual code looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function won($polaczenie, $error)
{
    $polaczenie->close();
    $_SESSION['error2'] = $error;
    session_write_close();
    header("Location: index.php?sesja=".session_id());
    exit();
}

function antyhakier($input,$polaczenie)
{
    $input = htmlentities($input, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $input = mysqli_real_escape_string($polaczenie, $input);
    return $input;
}

require_once "php/connect.php";
$polaczenie = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
$polaczenie->set_charset("utf8");
if($polaczenie->connect_errno!=0) echo "Twój numer na dzisiejsze losowanie lotto to: ".$polaczenie->connect_errno;

if(!isset($_GET['h'])) won($polaczenie,"Nie wprowadzono tajnego kodu Leonarda.");
$hash = antyhakier($_GET['h'],$polaczenie);

$rezultat = $polaczenie->query(sprintf("SELECT id FROM uzytkownicy WHERE hash='%s'",$hash));
$ile_userow = $rezultat->num_rows;
$wiersz = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat, MYSQL_BOTH);
$id = $wiersz['id'];
if($ile_userow==0) won($polaczenie,"Ale z Ciebie haker :*");
else
{
    $polaczenie -> query("UPDATE `uzytkownicy` SET `potwierdzony`=1 WHERE id='$id'");
    won($polaczenie,"Twój e-mail został potwierdzony. Teraz możesz się zalogować.");
}
?>
```

And after click on activation link I see in database that variable changed from 0 to 1 and I am redirected to index.php where I have:

```
if(isset($_GET['sesja'])) session_id($_GET['sesja']);
session_start();
```

and:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['error2']))
{
    echo '<script>alert("'.$_SESSION['error2'].'");</script>';
    unset($_SESSION['error2']);
}
```

Of course I don't see any error although I can see it after registration.php where I am using same "won" function... Really please for help because I am powerless.
Greatings and I hope you can help me guys.

Comment: Show the session_id function as well please.

Comment: This is normal function in PHP standard. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Comment: Oh, now that was my bad. Never heard about it. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Try removing session_start(); from where you use session_id($_GET['sesja']); What I mean is if (isset($_GET['sesja'])) {session_id($_GET['sesja']);} else { session_start(); }

Comment: Maybe this will work, let me know.

Comment: Your idea is not working :( I must to repeat that I use won function in register.php and for example if my email is not valid I am redirected to index.php and I see normal JS alert... It is very strange and I really don't know why. My domain has SSL certificate and connects are in https protocol.